# How to insert literal identifier from input pattern as symbol in syntax-rules macro

Tags: macros, scheme, hygiene

I have code like this:

```lisp
(define-syntax macron
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name)
     (lambda (x)
       (eval (cons 'name x) (interaction-environment))))))

(define x (map (macron lambda)
               '(((x) (display x)) ((a b) (+ a b)))))

(let ((square (car x)) 
      (sum (cadr x))) 
  (display (square 10)) 
  (newline) 
  (display (sum 1 2 3)) 
  (newline))
```

the code is working it use macro as value by wrapping it with lambda. My question is how can I put inside syntax-rule macro literal symbol `'name` instead of `(cons 'lambda ...)` so the output code is:

```lisp
(lambda (x)
  (eval (cons 'name x) (interaction-environment)))
```

so it work with code like this:

```lisp
(define (name x)
  (display x)
  (newline))

(for-each (macron lambda) ;; lambda can be anything
          '((1) (2) (3)))
```

and it print all the numbers.

I know that I can change the name in pattern into something else, but I want to know more about syntax-rules and it's edge cases. So is it possible to have name if I use it as input pattern?

I'm looking for answers with R7RS, that have more of this type of edge cases covered.

Comment: Can't you just make the pattern `(_ _)`?  However, the mere existence of `eval` in this is sufficiently terrifying that I'm not sure.

Comment: @tfb do you know any other way to create macro like macron with syntax-rules and without eval? I want to do apply on macro, was not able to find any other way.

Comment: I can't work out what you are actually trying to do.  If you describe that, then I am fairly sure there's a better answer than this.

Answer (score 2):

All macros happens in compile time so runtime stuff might not exist. That means that you should think of it as syntax sugar and use it as susch. eg.

```
(for-each (macron something) '((1) (2) (3)))
```

Should then have an expansion based on that. Your current expansion is that it turns into this:

```
(for-each (lambda (x)
            (eval (cons 'someting x) (interaction-environment))
          '((1) (2) (3)))
```

For `something` being a macro this will apply the macro in runtime. It is bad. It also removes the need for the macro in the first place. You could do this instead:

```
(define (macron-proc name)
  (lambda (x)
    (eval (cons name x) (interaction-environment))))

(for-each (macron-proc 'something) '((1) (2) (3)))
```

I made a programming language that had passable macros:

```
(define xor (flambda (a b) `(if ,a (not ,b) ,b)))
(define (fold comb init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (fold comb (comb (car lst) init) (cdr lst))))
(fold xor #f '(#t #t)) ; ==> #f
```

It's not a very good approach if you are targeting an efficient compiled end product. The first macros were indeed like this and they removed it in LISP 1.5 before Common Lisp. Scheme avoided macros for many years and opted for `syntax-rules` in R4RS as an optional feature. R6RS is the only version that has full power macros.

With a procedure instead of macros this is actually the same as the following code with the bad `eval` removed:

```
(for-each (lambda (x)
            (apply something x))
          '((1) (2) (3)))
```

Which means you can implement `macron` much easier:

```
(define-syntax macron
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name)
     (lambda (x)
       (apply name x)))))
```

But from looking at this now you don't need a macro at all. This is partial application.

```
(define (partial proc arg)
  (lambda (lst)
    (apply proc arh lst)))

(map (partial + 3) '((1 2) (3 4) (4 5)))
; ==> (6 10 12)
```

There is actually a [SRFI-26](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) called `cut`/`cute` which allows us to do something similar where it wraps it in a lambda:

```
(map (cut apply + 3 <>) '((1 2) (3 4) (4 5)))
```

The `syntax-rules` are the macros with the least power. You cannot do anything unhygienic and you cannot make new identifiers based on other ones. Eg. it' impossible to implement a racket style `struct` where you can do `(struct complex [real imag])` and have the macro create `complex?`, `complex-real`, and `complex-imag` as procedures.  You need to do as [SRFI-57](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-57/srfi-57.html) does and require th euser to specify all the names such that you don't need to concatenate to new identifiers.

Right now R7RS-small only has `syntax-rules`. I think it was a mistake not to have a more powerful macro as an alternative since now the R7RS-large cannot be implemented with R7RS-small.

Comment: `partial` will only work when `proc` is a procedure, but OP wants `macron` to work when `name` is either a procedure or a macro.

Comment: @exnihilo Still don't need a macro if one uses `eval` anyway. Scheme macros, even `syntax-case` cannot be used as a passable object. I think this is a XY

Comment: I actually don't care about performance and compile optimization, this is mainly as exercise, I'm  testing int my Scheme that don't have compilation step and macros are first class objects the same as function, it should be easy to modify apply to work with macros. But I want something that will also work in other Scheme implementations. This don't even remotely close to answering my question. I know about apply and how to use it. My question is about injecting literal symbol (and my example is or macros not functions), this is not XY question because I don't need this to solving a problem.

Comment: With functions I can do the same with curry that is much simpler `(map (curry apply +) '((1 2) (2 4) (4 5)))`

Comment: @jcubic AFAIK `curry` isn't a part of Scheme. Where is the documentation?. `cut` isn't either, but it [has a SRFI](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-57/srfi-57.html). Maybe we are not talking about Scheme no more since you are talking about first class macros? I wouldn't use `syntax-rules` at all if I were to implement that and since you're not bound by a standard I'm guessing you're shortest route is `flambda`/`gensym`

Comment: @Sylwester `curry` is not standard but it's trivial to create. The same as `filter` function, they both are known from other languages, they are pretty well defined.

Comment: @jcubic Not really. `curry` is well defined in curried languages like Haskell and lambda calculus, but in an applied language with more than one argument it is not well defined what it should do or how it supposed to work. This is also mentioned in the design rationale of SRFI-26. `filter` is defined in [SRFI-1 List Library](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning) and SRFI-1 is the list library of [R7RS-Red](https://small.r7rs.org/wiki/RedEdition/) under (scheme list)